# Faster alternatives to aggregating with pandas.groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program which spends a lot of time doing this:

```
agg_df[['foo', 'bar', 'baz']] = df.groupby('some_ID')['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].sum()
```

Speed is of the essence, and `groupby` is pretty slow, so I would like to accomplish the same thing in some faster way. Ideally I'd like something that could benefit from `numba.njit`, but any kind of improvement will do. So far all I've got is a minor improvement from adding `sorted=False` to the `groupby` call.

My data is already sorted by most of the `some_ID`'s I'm grouping by, if that helps in any way. I am happy to leave `pandas` and operate only on the underlying arrays, but better `pandas`ing is also good.

How can I improve this aggregation?

Comment: @jezrael I wish I could upvote a "marked as duplicate", thanks!

Comment: Better is upvote all solution what help you from duplicated answers :)

Comment: Already did that ;)